# SQL Server Data Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have data in the format:

```
Date, FirstName, LastName, Unit
Jan1 , Bob      , Guy     , Home
Jan2 , Bob      , Guy     , Home
Jan3 , Bob      , Guy     , Home
Jan5 , Bob      , Guy     , Home
Jan6 , Bob      , Guy     , Home
Jan7 , Bob      , Guy     , Home
Jan8 , Bob      , Guy     , Offsite
Jan3 , Jane     , Doe     , Home
Jan4 , Jane     , Doe     , Home
Jan5 , Jane     , Doe     , Home
Jan9 , Bob      , Guy     , Home
Jan10, Bob      , Guy     , Home
Jan11, Bob      , Guy     , Home
Jan12, Jane     , Doe     , Home
Jan13, Jane     , Doe     , Home
Jan14, Jane     , Doe     , Home
```

and I want it in the format

```
DateStart, DateEnd, FirstName, LastName, Unit
Jan1     , Jan3   , Bob      , Guy     , Home
Jan5     , Jan7   , Bob      , Guy     , Home
Jan8     , Jan8   , Bob      , Guy     , Offsite
Jan3     , Jan5   , Jane     , Doe     , Home
Jan9     , Jan11  , Bob      , Guy     , Home
Jan12    , Jan14  , Jane     , Doe     , Home
```

Edit: Updated the data.

How can I convert the data easily?

This is a one time conversion.

Thanks for the comments/answers!

Comment: Not totally clear what you're trying to do; e.g. why is "DateEnd" = Jan3 for Jane Doe, while it's null for Bob Guy?? Could there be more than two entries for a given first/last name?? If yes: would you want to have DateStart = MIN(Date) and DateEnd = MAX(Date) for that name??

Comment: Agreed with marc_s... I would expect Jane Doe to have a null  DateEnd just like Bob by your explanation? Otherwise do you mean that the final row only will have no DateEnd?

Comment: @marc_s & @Matthew PK Bob's DateEnd is null because he is the last person to be in the unit. There can be many entries for a given firstname/lastname. There could be more entries for 'Home' after Jan4 which would make the Jan4 entry on the second table to have a DateEnd of Jan4 (if it is a different person) or to be another date if Bob had several more entries and then another person had an entry on the home unit after him. The most recent DateStart for each unit will have a null DateEnd

Comment: What if two people have the same date on the final date of the Unit?

Comment: I recant my previous statement about null DateEnds. :( They make it more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL below will produce the desired output, But I'm not sure if you're not better off writing this is C#

**Update**
This has been updated to a proper gaps and island solution. This is based on the MSDN article [Islands and Gaps in Sequential Numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175780%28SQL.80%29.aspx) by Alexander Kozak. This could be improved on by using CTE's and also the Exists could be replaced with LEFT JOINs.

It should be noted that this relies on the Dates to not have any time component. If there were a time component it would have to be removed up front.

Output

```
Date                    enddate                 FirstName LastName Unit
----------------------- ----------------------- --------- -------- -------
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 Bob       Guy      Home
2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 2011-01-05 00:00:00.000 Jane      Doe      Home
2011-01-05 00:00:00.000 2011-01-07 00:00:00.000 Bob       Guy      Home
2011-01-08 00:00:00.000 2011-01-08 00:00:00.000 Bob       Guy      Offsite
2011-01-09 00:00:00.000 2011-01-11 00:00:00.000 Bob       Guy      Home
2011-01-12 00:00:00.000 2011-01-14 00:00:00.000 Jane      Doe      Home
```

SQL Statement

```
SET NOCOUNT On

DECLARE @Test 
Table (
    Date datetime, 
    FirstName varchar(100),
     LastName varchar(100), 
     Unit  varchar(7))



INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/01/2011'  , 'Bob', 'Guy',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/02/2011'  , 'Bob', 'Guy',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/03/2011'  , 'Bob', 'Guy',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/05/2011'  , 'Bob', 'Guy',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/06/2011'  , 'Bob', 'Guy',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/07/2011'  , 'Bob', 'Guy',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/08/2011'  , 'Bob', 'Guy',  'Offsite')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/03/2011'  , 'Jane', 'Doe',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/04/2011'  , 'Jane', 'Doe',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/05/2011'  , 'Jane', 'Doe',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/09/2011'  , 'Bob', 'Guy',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/10/2011'  , 'Bob', 'Guy',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/11/2011'  , 'Bob', 'Guy',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/12/2011'  , 'Jane', 'Doe',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/13/2011'  , 'Jane', 'Doe',  'Home')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('01/14/2011'  , 'Jane', 'Doe',  'Home')


SELECT 
    t1.Date,
    MIN(t2.Date) enddate, 
    t1.FirstName,
    t1.LastName,
    t1.Unit
 FROM

    (SELECT * 
    FROM
        @Test t1
    WHERE
       NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Test t2
                  WHERE
                      t1.firstName = t2.FirstName   
                      AND t1.LastName = t2.LastName
                      AND t1.Unit = t2.Unit
                        and t1.Date - t2.Date = 1)) 
        t1


      INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM @Test t1

    WHERE
       NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Test t2
                  WHERE
                      t1.firstName = t2.FirstName   
                      AND t1.LastName = t2.LastName
                      AND t1.Unit = t2.Unit
                        and t2.Date - t1.Date = 1)) t2
      ON
        t1.firstName = t2.FirstName 
                      AND t1.LastName = t2.LastName
                      AND t1.Unit = t2.Unit
                      AND t1.Date <= t2.Date  
       GROUP BY
       t1.Date,
       t1.FirstName,
       t1.LastName,
       t1.Unit
```

Comment: Excellent, I'm going to change "Min(t2.date) todate," to "ISNULL(Min(t2.date), t.Date) toDate," and I think I'm in business! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm, when run against my data I'm getting 2 day schedules. I might have to do some more digging.

Comment: @Bill feel free to add more samples to your question

Comment: @Conrad Frix Thanks! I've tried to make what I'm doing clearer.

Comment: @Biff (sorry for calling you Bill before I was on a smartphone and the f's looked like l's) Yes this can be done. Its the Gaps and Islands problem. I'll update my answer

Comment: +1 If on SQL Server 2005+ I would have thought ranking functions would be simpler and more efficient though.

Answer (score 4):

Using Conrad's test data and Itzik Ben Gan's approach!

```
;WITH base AS ( 
SELECT    FirstName, 
          LastName, 
          Unit,
          Date,
          DATEDIFF(DAY,0,Date) - 
                         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName, Unit 
                                            ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY,0,Date)) AS G
 FROM     @Test
 )
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Unit, MIN(Date) DateStart,MAX(Date) DateEnd
FROM base
GROUP BY G, FirstName, LastName, Unit
```

Comment: +! @Martin. Very nice. I was looking for a ranking approach but couldn't find one.