# Sickness Extract query checking for consecutive dates in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in my database (SQL Server 2008) with the following columns/data.

```
 Emp ID        Start DT       End DT        Start Time     End Time     ABSTYPE      
20011664      13/02/2013     13/02/2013     09:00         17:00         Sick
20011664      14/02/2013     14/02/2013     09:00         17:00         Sick
20011664      15/02/2013     15/02/2013     09:00         17:00         Sick
20011664      19/02/2013     19/02/2013     09:00         17:00         Sick
20099999      14/02/2013     14/02/2013     09:00         17:00         Sick
```

I want a query which will return the following

```
20011664      13/02/2013      15/02/2013    09:00         17:00         Sick
20011664      19/02/2013      19/02/2013    09:00         17:00         Sick
20099999      14/02/2013      14/02/2013    09:00         17:00         Sick
```

i.e, Return one row for each period of continuous sickness

Comment: Why are you separating the dates and times? And what have you tried already?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Data Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630560/sql-server-data-conversion)

Comment: Extarct dates from the Query within same month. check wheteher date digfference equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl ([Emp ID]   INT,     [Start DT]     DATE,  [End DT]     DATE,   [Start Time]    TIME, [End Time] TIME, ABSTYPE VARCHAR(100))
INSERT #tbl VALUES
(20011664,      '13/02/2013' ,    '13/02/2013'  ,   '09:00'    ,     '17:00'    ,     'Sick'),
(20011664,      '14/02/2013' ,    '14/02/2013'  ,   '09:00'    ,     '17:00'    ,     'Sick'),
(20011664,      '15/02/2013' ,    '15/02/2013'  ,   '09:00'    ,     '17:00'    ,     'Sick'),
(20011664,      '19/02/2013' ,    '19/02/2013'  ,   '09:00'    ,     '17:00'    ,     'Sick'),
(20099999,      '14/02/2013' ,    '14/02/2013'  ,   '09:00'    ,     '17:00'    ,     'Sick')

;WITH a AS
(
    SELECT  *
            , DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Start DT]) - 
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Emp ID] ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [Start DT])) 
                AS part
    FROM    #tbl
)

SELECT  a.[Emp ID]
        , MIN(a.[Start DT])
        , MAX(a.[End DT])
FROM    a
GROUP BY
        a.[Emp ID], a.part
```

This wonderful method was taken from Martin Smith's answer (**[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630560/sql-server-data-conversion)**) and adjusted for this example, according to Martin it was introduced by Itzik Ben Gan.

Comment: Nice. I think you could achieve the same result in this case by using `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [Emp ID] ORDER BY [Start DT])` instead of `dense_rank()`

Comment: I'm affraid result would be wrong in case of `ROW_NUMBER`, `DENSE_RANK` is used so that the ties would be handled correctly, tie would be if there would be 2 or more rows that have equal `[Emp ID]` and `[Start DT]`. You can test this by inserting one more previously inserted row.

Comment: This is the thing, in this case, the data suggests this wouldn't happen. Good to know though.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as (
    select *
    from [<YourTable>]

    union all

    select t.[Emp ID], t.[Start DT], t.[End DT] + 1, t.[Start Time], t.[End Time], t.[ABSTYPE]
    from cte t
    inner join [<YourTable>] d on t.[Emp ID] = d.[Emp ID] and t.[End DT] + 1 = d.[Start DT]
), results as (
    select *, datediff(day, [Start DT], [End DT]) as daydiff, max(datediff(day, [Start DT], [End DT])) over (partition by [Emp ID], [Start DT]) as max_start_daydiff, max(datediff(day, [Start DT], [End DT])) over (partition by [Emp ID], [End DT]) as max_end_daydiff
    from cte 
)
select [Emp ID], [Start DT], [End DT], [Start Time], [End Time], [ABSTYPE]
from results
where daydiff = max_start_daydiff
and daydiff = max_end_daydiff
```